# How to display a list of lists in a nice way

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists, such as below.

Each list (e.g. list1, list2, list3) has two attributes: Variable and Time

```
list1 <- list(c("Color", "Price"), "Quarter")
list2 <- list(c("Price"), "Month")
list3 <- list(c("Color"), "Month")
total <- list(list1, list2, list3)
```

when we print `total`, we'll see:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "Color" "Price"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "Quarter"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "Price"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "Month"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "Color"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "Month"
```

How can I turn it into a data frame such as this one?

[image]

```
EDIT: I am able to accomplish it using this code. Any better suggestion is appreciated!

  num <- length(total)
  max      <- 0
  for(i in 1:num) {
    if(length(total[[i]][1]) > max) {
      max <- length(total[[i]])
    }
  }

  for(i in 1:num) {
    length(total[[i]][[1]]) <- max
    for(j in 1:max) {
      if(is.null(total[[i]][[1]][[j]])) {
        total[[i]][[1]][[j]] <- " "
      }
    }
  }

  df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(total), nrow=num, byrow=T))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested named list to data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491921/nested-named-list-to-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Literally *none* of the answers provided in those two suggested duplicates work for this data, since the lists have different lengths. It's unclear why (for instance) the first list here has 2 elems in one nested list and 1 elem in another, yet it is shown homogenously in the suggested output. Perhaps some clarity, Ketty?

Comment: Ok, Ketty, I see why you've done the sub-nesting. Yeah, that's pretty obscure, frankly. Do you have any control over the format of the data? There are likely more efficient and data-friendly ways of storing that kind of information. (@divibisan and @camille, your duplicate suggestion is premature and I suggest you remove them.)

Comment: r2evans. Unfortunately, I don't have the original script. I am trying to work with what I have. Any idea?

Comment: It's not written in COBOL, is it? I've found many problems over the years are sustained because not many people grok COBOL and are hesitant to try to refactor the software :-) (I'm confident it isn't ... COBOL doesn't really have a good concept of lists like this ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't just a nested-`list` problem, it's a nested problem. If I'm interpretting things correctly, the fact that Color and Price are in one list and Quarter is in another is meaningful. So really, you should be looking at how to turn the first element of each list into a `data.frame`, repeat for all other elements, then join the results. (This is where @divibisan's and @camille's suggestions come into play ... reduce the problem, use the duplicates' code, then combine.)

(The fact that I believe you will never have more than two elems in each list is not strictly a factor. Below is a general way of handling 1-or-more, not just "always 2".)

Your data:

```
str(total)
# List of 3
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "Color" "Price"
#   ..$ : chr "Quarter"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "Price"
#   ..$ : chr "Month"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "Color"
#   ..$ : chr "Month"
```

What we need to do is break this down by element-of-each-list. (I'm assuming that there will be symmetry here.) Let's start by just working on the first elem of each:

```
total1 <- lapply(total, `[[`, 1)
str(total1)
# List of 3
#  $ : chr [1:2] "Color" "Price"
#  $ : chr "Price"
#  $ : chr "Color"
```

In order to use the suggestions from the dupes, we need to know how much to pad them. That is, they need to be the same length.

```
( maxlen <- max(sapply(total1, function(l) length(unlist(l)))) )
# [1] 2
```

Now we pad them:

```
total1 <- lapply(total1, function(l) { length(l) <- maxlen; l; })
str(total1)
# List of 3
#  $ : chr [1:2] "Color" "Price"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "Price" NA
#  $ : chr [1:2] "Color" NA
```

(You can start to see the structure break out here.) The dupes suggested `cbind`ing them, but you want to `rbind` them:

```
do.call(rbind, total1)
#      [,1]    [,2]   
# [1,] "Color" "Price"
# [2,] "Price" NA     
# [3,] "Color" NA
```

Now this is a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`, but it's a start. Let's work with naming at the end. Let's write a function to do what we just did, and then we'll use it on each level of `total`.

In order to do this, though, we need to modify `total`, so that the new first element has all first elements, new second has all seconds, etc.

```
newtotal <- lapply(seq_len(max(sapply(total, length))), function(i) lapply(total, `[[`, i))
str(newtotal)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "Color" "Price"
#   ..$ : chr "Price"
#   ..$ : chr "Color"
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ : chr "Quarter"
#   ..$ : chr "Month"
#   ..$ : chr "Month"
m <- do.call(cbind, lapply(newtotal, func))
m
#      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]     
# [1,] "Color" "Price" "Quarter"
# [2,] "Price" NA      "Month"  
# [3,] "Color" NA      "Month"
```

So this last point is pretty much what you need, though as a `matrix`. From here, it's easy enough to name things:

```
m <- do.call(cbind, lapply(newtotal, func))
colnames(m) <- c(paste0("Var", seq_len(ncol(m)-1L)), "Time")
df <- as.data.frame(m)
df$List <- paste0('List', seq_len(nrow(df)))
df
#    Var1  Var2    Time  List
# 1 Color Price Quarter List1
# 2 Price  <NA>   Month List2
# 3 Color  <NA>   Month List3
```